# Como pegar dados do mysql para um carrinho de comprar

Tags: php

Bom eu gostaria de saber se existe um metodo melhor que esse:
ele procura tudo que tem skin_tipo==2, e eu queria fazer diversos tipos para vender, teria um jeito de eu pegar item por item e por em uma div ou apenas assim pegando tudo ?

```
 <?php
                $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM homesite");
                $consulta -> execute();

                $linhas = $consulta -> rowCount();

                foreach($consulta as $mostra):
            ?>
    <div class="card">
        <?php
if ($mostra['skin_tipo'] == 2) {?>
      <img class="skin"src="images/<?= $mostra['skin_img']?>" alt="Nome da Empresa: 
      <?= $mostra['skin_nome']?>" title="Nome da Empresa: <?= $mostra['skin_nome']?>">
      <div class="info">
      <h1 class="color-white text-center font-text-light-med font-weight-heavy bgcolor-black"><?= $mostra['skin_nome']?></h1> 
      </div>
      <p class="preccor">Por: R$ <?= number_format($mostra['skin_preco'], 2,',','.')?></p>
      <button class="bgcolor-red text-center btn"><a href="comprar.php?prod=<?= $mostra['id_skin']?>">Comprar</a></button>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Você quer mostrar apenas o que é skin_tipo==2?

Comment: Isso eu já fiz, eu queria pegar item por item, que tenho o skin_tipo == 2, desse modo que eu fiz ele pega tudo, pq eu queria fazer um caroulse com cada item que tenha tipo = = 2

Comment: eu tou tentando pegar pelo id, mas mesmo assim pega todos os registro do campo, e eu queria pegar apenas 1 por vez..

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo eu estava querendo puxar separadamente cada ( produto que está cadastrado no banco de dados), e no momento meu codigo busca todos os produtos cadastrados no mysql e não de 1 por 1 ex: se eu por lá pelo id, vai aparecer 5 mesmo eu tendo definido para apenas o id = 1.

Comment: Eu queria pegar separadamente item por item, para fazer um carousel

Comment: eu utilizei um if ($mostra['id_skin'] ==1)

Comment: mas mesmo com esse if aparece tudo que tem na table.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo nesse caso o melhor para se usar é esse from homesite where id=1?, mas ai eu teria q fazer isso para todos os itens ex se eu quiser pegar 5, teriam q ser 5 from homesite where, existe alguma maneira mais clean de se fazer isso? Eu queria criar  meio que um slide com produtos .

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo e teria como fazer um carousel puxando entre o 5 e 10?  Pois o carousel precisaria de itens separadamente não?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo é exatamente esse carousel que está na parte de novidades. http://www.neshastore.com/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83924/discussion-between-leo-caracciolo-and-felipe).

Comment: seu problema está em montar o carroussel né? entra no chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Traga na consulta somente aqueles que tiverem `skin_tipo=2`

   ```
   $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM homesite WHERE skin_tipo=2");
   ```
2. Troque essas linhas

   ```
     $linhas = $consulta -> rowCount();
     foreach($consulta as $mostra):
   ```

   por essas

   ```
     $fetchAll = $consulta->fetchAll(); 
     foreach($consulta as $mostra):
   ```

**Código**

```
$consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM homesite WHERE skin_tipo=2"); 
$consulta -> execute(); 

$fetchAll = $consulta->fetchAll(); 

foreach($consulta as $mostra): 

  // o que quer seja apresentado

endforeach;
```

Comment: quando tiver um tempo vamos chat continuar aquele assunto ?